# Remotley initiate a local login

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have a situation where i wish to remotely cause a local login on a computer, in order to start up some applications that need an interactive session even when working on a script.

IE.

- Computer powered on via Wake On Lan.
- Computer is started up, and in the Press CTRL+ALT+DEL to log on
- From this I wish to cause a local login on the console (this is to get access to all hardware acceleration) without performing the interactive steps of pressing the keyboard and clicking the mouse.
- After login has been confirmed remotely I'll run applications/scripts via PsExec, and lastly will shut down the computer.

Computer is currently Windows 7, but can change it to a Windows 10 without much fuzz. Automatically log on is not an solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of VNC solutions.

RealVNC (perhaps even UltraVNC) has a server service that can be installed. This service can be configured to run as a system user and allows you to connect to your computer even without a user logged on (so you can see the "Ctrl + Alt + Del" screen) and allow you to log on with the desired local user. The system user is required so that the service can run without a normal user already having to be logged on.

Comment: The problem with this, is that I cannot automate the login via VNC, I believe i still have to do the interactive keyboard presses and mouse clicking.

Comment: Ah, your description doesn't converse that that's a requirement... OK

Comment: Sorry! That is now also specified.

Comment: Couldn't you create a `.rdp` file that contains the username/password of the local user and then get your console to run `mstsc` with the RDP file as an argument. You can then get your script to do what it needs to do?

Comment: My understanding is that when RDP'ing a lot of the hardware acceleration is not utilized. In my case it is mostly Accelerated Graphics that is required to do rendering during off-hours.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to only using RDP to perform the login. i thought the rest you were doing as a remote console "After login has been confirmed remotely I'll run applications/scripts via PsExec"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64352/discussion-between-gnutt-and-kinnectus).